# Apache, 20+ long running connections with little memory usage

Tags: apache-2.4, memory

I have a small server, 2 GB memory (an AWS t2.small) that I would like to run cron jobs on. These crons run by specific URLs getting hit (an AWS setup I can’t change), and take maybe 1 – 2 minutes each to complete.

At some points during the day there are ~20 crons that run at exactly the same time. Predictably, this is causing memory usage to spike and shut things down. I reduced `MaxClients` to 6, which fixed the memory usage spike problem, but this is causing some crons to silently not be run.

From my understanding of `MaxClients`, these crons are silently failing because only 6 connections are allowed at one time? Is there any way my little server can handle these spikes of 20 connections and keep memory usage stable? It seems like my goal would be "allow 20+ connections, but only allocate a small amount of memory to each".

Thanks for your help

Comment: Run the cronjobs in serial, one by another?

Comment: @Thomas yes there are solutions like that, but my team doesn't want to change their code or their cron schedules right now. They want me to come up with a server solution, if possible